# Can I disable killcam?

Tags: call-of-duty-infinite-warfare

[Killcam](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/KillCam) (shows the player's death from the perspective of the killer) is always played after death, a key press is required to skip the video.

Comment: cant you just spam it? Its the square button on ps4 and i do it by habit so that the killcam doesnt even show up.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket: Of course, but naturally it gets repetitive quickly when the average life expectancy is measured in seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to disable the killcam in Core game types.  None of the in game options allow for this (checked for myself).

In Hardcore game types it is always disabled.